# Are there any examples of "autonomous" TSP heuristics

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman-problem

By "autonomous" TSP heuristic I mean algorithms whose reported edge-set for a short Hamilton cycle is invariant under the addition of vertex weights;
the terminology is borrowed from differential equations,  interpreting vertex weights in TSP as corresponding to parameters in differential equations and edge-set to trace.

> **Question:**
>
> despite intensive online search I could not find any TSP heuristic whose reported edges set can't be affected by the addition of vertex weights; so my question is if I overlooked such kind of "autonomous" heuristics and what are they?

Comment: For TSP, the objective function depends only on edge weights. If you want to modify the objective function to also include vertex weights, that is equivalent to adding a constant because every vertex is visited exactly once.

Comment: @RobPratt regarding the objective you are of course right, but the question is about heuristics and there the story is different; for tour expansion heuristics for example the edge set of the generated tour depends on the insertion order of the vertices and that order depends crucially on the vertex weights.

Comment: All the common TSP heuristics use only the edge weights.  For example, nearest neighbor starts at a vertex and visits the closest unvisited vertex, where "closest" means minimum of incident edge weights.

Comment: @RobPratt I suspected that; it is however possible to formulate tour expansion in a way that makes it independent of vertex weights...